# Multithreading improvements in .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0

I have heard that the .NET 4 team has added new classes in the framework that make working with threads better and easier.

Basically the question is what are the new ways to run multithreaded tasks added in .NET 4 and what are they designed to be used for?

**UPD:** Just to make it clear, I'm not looking for *a single* way of running parallel tasks in .NET 4, I want to find out which are the new ones added, and if possible what situation would *each* of them be best suited for..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

With the lack of responses, I decided to evaluate on the answers below with that I've learned..
As @Scott stated, .NET 4 added the Task Parallel Library which adds a number of innovations, new methods and approaches to parallelism.

- One of the first things to mention is the `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.ForEach` methods, which allow the developer to process multiple items in multiple threads. The Framework in this case will decide how many threads are necessary, and when to create new threads, and when not to.
  This is a very simple and straightforward way to parallelize existing code, and add some performance boost.
- Another way, somewhat similar to the previous approaches is using the PLINQ extenders. They take an existing enumeration, and extend it with parallel linq extenders. So if you have an existing linq query, you can easily convert it to PLINQ. What this means is all the operations on the PLINQ enumerable will also take advantage of multiple threads, and filtering your list of objects using a `.Where` clause, for example, will run in multiple threads now!
- One of the bigger innovations in the TPL is the new `Task` class. In some ways it may look like the already well known `Thread` class, but it takes advantage of the new Thread Pool in .NET 4 (which has been improved a lot compared on previous versions), and is much more functional than the regular `Thread` class. For example you can chain Tasks where tasks in the middle of the chain will only start when the previous ones finish. Examples and in-depth explanation in a screencast on [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/philpenn/Task-and-TaskTResult-Waiting-and-Continuations/)
- To enhance the work with Task classes, we can use the `BlockingCollection<>`. This works perfectly in situations where you have a producer-consumer scenario. You can have multiple threads producing some objects, that will then be consumed and processed by consumer methods. This can be easily parallelised and controlled with the Task factory and the blocking collection. Useful screencast with examples from [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/philpenn/BlockingCollectionT-Demonstration-in-Producer-Consumer-Scenarios/)
  These can also use different backing storage classes (ConcurrentQueue, ConcurentStack, ConcurrentBag), which are all thread safe, and are different in terms of element ordering and performance. Examples and explanations of them in a different [video here](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/philpenn/Concurrent-Programming-with-NET4-Collections/)
- One more new thing that has been added (which probably isn't part of the TPL, but helps us here anyway) is the `CountdownEvent` class, which can help us in "task coordination scenarios" (c). Basically allows us to wait until all parallel tasks are finished. Screencast with example usage on [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/philpenn/The-NET4-Countdown-Synchronization-Primitive/)

You can see a number of screencasts and videos on Channel 9 that are tagged with ["Parallel Computing"](http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/Parallel+Computing/)

Answer (score 15):

Yes, .NET 4 added the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(VS.100).aspx)  which, at a high level, adds support for:

- running parallel loops with `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.ForEach`
- create or run tasks using `Parallel.Invoke` or the `Task` class
- PLINQ (parallel LINQ to Objects)

Answering the update to the original question...

The TPL is the *preferred* way of writing parallel tasks using .NET 4. You can still create threadpool items yourself, and do all of the same "manual" threading techniques you could before. The thing to keep in mind is that the entire threadpool (and pretty much everything threading related) has been rewritten to take advantage of the TPL. This means that even if you create a threadpool item yourself you still end up using the TPL, even if you don't know it. The other thing to keep in mind is that the TPL is much more optimized, and will scale more appropriately based on the number of available processors.

As for knowing what situation each of them would be best suited for, there is no "silver bullet" answer. If you were previously queueing your own threadpool item (or otherwise doing something multi-threaded) you can modify that portion of your code to use the TPL without any consequences.

For things like parallel loops or parallel queries, you will need to analyze the code and the execution of that code to determine if it is appropriate to be parallelized.

Comment: +1 for the TPL reference and a couple of examples.. But TPL is a whole library in .NET, while I was looking for more concrete examples..

Comment: TPL is a whole library, but it was added as part of .NET 4 and is the preferred way to write multi-threaded apps in .NET 4. Seeing as how your answer and mine are similar, I'm not seeing how this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: I know that TPL was added in .NET4, and I know that it's the preferred way. I was asking for classes and methodologies inside the tpl. My answer describes some of them + examples, you just pointed to 3, and no examples/explanation at all.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking this is C# 4.0 and not a new class, but events [now have a smarter form of locking](http://blogs.msdn.com/cburrows/archive/2010/03/05/events-get-a-little-overhaul-in-c-4-part-i-locks.aspx) which if I've understood the change correctly, **removes** the need for reems of locking code as shown below (taken from [this article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/events.html) by Jon Skeet):

```
SomeEventHandler someEvent;
readonly object someEventLock = new object();

public event SomeEventHandler SomeEvent
{
    add
    {
        lock (someEventLock)
        {
            someEvent += value;
        }
    }
    remove
    {
        lock (someEventLock)
        {
            someEvent -= value;
        }
    }
}
```